# Extract results from Presto in the form of JSON

Tags: sql, presto, presto-jdbc

I have a presto view from where I need to create nested JSON. I have tried with the below query:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(ROW('Sales (PTD)' as Ttl,unsale as Val) AS ROW(v1 VARCHAR, v2 VARCHAR)) AS JSON)
from metrics_v where time_frame='PTD';
```

I need a JSON result like below:

```
"SlsPTD": {
    "Ttl": "Sales (PTD)",
    "Val": "103.27290344238281"
  }
```

But it is currently throwing error:
SQL Error [1]: Query failed (#20220725_063102_03638_j2tav): line 1:36: mismatched input 'as'. Expecting: ')', ','

How to get the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it is currently throwing error: SQL Error [1](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-to-json): Query failed (#20220725_063102_03638_j2tav): line 1:36: mismatched input 'as'. Expecting: ')', ','

the issue here is incorrect syntax for `ROW` instantioation, correct query can look like:

```sql
SELECT CAST(
        CAST(
            ROW('Sales (PTD)', unsale) AS ROW(Ttl VARCHAR, Val VARCHAR)
        ) AS JSON
    )
from dataset
where time_frame = 'PTD';
```

But `ROW` is incorrect data structure here, cause presto does not treat  it as key-value pairs but rather as a collection of values (i.e. an array, see the [cast to json](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#cast-to-json) doc). You can use [`MAP`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/language/types.html#map):

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(unsale, time_frame) AS (
    VALUES ('103.27290344238281', 'PTD')
) 

-- query
SELECT CAST(
        map(
            array [ 'SlsPTD' ],
            array [ map(array [ 'Ttl', 'Val' ], array [ 'Sales (PTD)', unsale ]) ]
        ) AS JSON
    )
from dataset
where time_frame = 'PTD';
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| {"SlsPTD":{"Ttl":"Sales (PTD)","Val":"103.27290344238281"}} |